# Opposite of nothingness

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of nothingness? I got *fullness* as a word but that's not exactly the word I'm looking for; I'm looking for a word that kind of means 'something infinite' Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Like *everything*? Or *infinity*?

Comment: Perhaps *abundance* or *somethingness*?

Comment: "Cosmos" or "universe" would be antonyms in the sense of meaning everything instead of the absence of anything.  Another approach was taken by Jean-Paul Sartre, the French philospher, who contrasted Nothingness with Being, i.e. existence.

Comment: First you have to produce a definition of _nothingness_ that distinguishes it in a reliable manner from _nothing_, without any hidden presuppositions. Then we can talk.

Comment: Smith of Lensman fame used 'the Cosmic All'. But I find it hard to believe in its opposite, 'nothingness'.

Comment: @AlMaki has an answer I was leaning towards, however I believe there is more than what those pesky empirical physicists often restrain themselves to as things that can't be measured don't exist for them.  Being takes in some philosophy, but choosing an existentialist is limiting too with their concentration on self and perception.  ;) Mysticism opens the doors to so much more. A "soul",  a possible essence of the energy from "love" or "grace" that persists beyond "being". Also, what of history? The Past, the present, AND the Future? :)

Answer (score -2):

'Something infinite' can be called *all-encompassing*.

> **all-encompassing** *adjective*
>   Including or covering everything or everyone; comprehensive.
>   ‘an all-encompassing package to combat global warming’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all-encompassing)

Comment: "All encompassing" is an adjective, OP is looking for a noun.